# How do I get my images into Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow, and I am following the Mnist simple tutorial. Now I would like to do something similar with my own images. I cannot figure out how to do that. The tutorial does this:

```
  batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
```

What precisely should batch_xs, batch_ys be when I create it from my images?

I see there is a library ImageFlow, and this seems to do exactly what I want, but I cannot figure out how to use that either. The description says I should call

```
  convert_images(images, labels, filename)
```

but that does not even contain a path to my images.

Many thanks for your attention.

Comment: I should improve the documentation, but for your problem what 'images' means in the input arguments is you should read it from other library e.g. 'cv2' and giving those array of images as a parameter to 'convert_images' method + their labels to convert both to a binary format. Hope this helps, if not let me know what else is not clear

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the implementation of [`mnist.train.next_batch()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c54b03ad9c6bbb40d6a3adb2ca6a43333cde87e0/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/input_data.py#L151), it appears that `batch_xs` should be a matrix of size `batch_size` x `num_pixels`, and `batch_ys` should be either a matrix of size `batch_size` x `num_classes` (if `one_hot` is True) or a vector of length `batch_size` (otherwise).

When you call `mnist.train.next_batch(100)`, `batch_xs` will be `100` x `784`, and `batch_ys` will be `100` x `10`. For your own application you will probably want to change both the number of pixels and the number of classes.